# NokiaX wont landscape my activity

Tags: nokiax

In my android manifest file I have attributed my activity to force it to  `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`, but the runtime still refuses to landscape my view, instead continues to be `protrait`.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.taxeeta.DriverHome"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this, and made new "Helloworld" application, and then in the manifest just added these two lines inside the opening part of the activity tag

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

And when it is run in the Nokia X device, it indeed opens nicely in landscape.